# Question incorrectly closed as duplicate

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I have just found this question which was closed as duplicate:

[How do I mark a user's progress when they're taking a multi-step action on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059475/how-to-i-implement-the-feature-of-rememebering-where-the-user-was-in-my-website)

however, it doesn't look like it is a duplicate, so I voted to reopen it and also flagged for moderator attention for it was wrongly closed, was this the right course of action or did I do something wrong?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Voting to reopen was all you needed to do. A comment as to *why* you feel it should be reopened could be really helpful.

There is a [reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) where other community members with 3k+ reputation review reopen requests; voting to reopen puts a question into that queue automatically if it has not yet been part of that queue.

You do **not** need to flag such a post for moderator attention. Moderators only need to be involved for issues the community cannot handle themselves. This is not such an issue.

Comment: It would seem I've done to much then, whops! Is there a way to "retract" a flag?

Comment: No, there isn't. The flag will most likely be declined when a moderator processes it. Don't worry too much about it, mistakes happen.

Comment: As someone who reviews reopen requests whenever I see one, I would really appreciate a comment explaining why it is not a duplicate. I'm going to look at the question and alleged duplicate anyway, but it is likely to make it easier and quicker for me to decide on my vote.